# Can fopen() with "w" ever fail with ENOENT? Why?

Tags: c

If fopen() creates a file if you want to write to a non-existent file, then is it even possible for it to fail and set errno to ENOENT?

If such a scenario exists, please describe.

Does the Standard say anything about it?

C99 gcc

Comment: `fopen("/no/no/no/no/no/info.txt", "w")`

Comment: See manual for underlying system call for your OS. E.g. `open()` on Linux: *ENOENT A directory component in pathname does not exist or is a  dangling symbolic link.*

Comment: `ENOENT` isn't part of any C standard so it doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: This is a hypothetical question, not a question about an actual issue.  As @pmg has hinted at, the path has to exist, and fopen cannot creat a non-existent directory path.  fopen may fail and set error, the actual value of error is platform specific.

Comment: @Clifford I tried it and you are right. I must say, this behaviour is unexpected. If it can create a file, why not the folder? How the heck can I create a folder? I need a multilevel hierarchy and I expected this to be handled automatically.

Comment: @basedchad21 Well, files and folders are different, and `fopen` is explicitly specified not to handle folder creation (which would be confusing and error-prone). There are separate functions for that (such as `mkdir`).

Comment: @basedchad21 Why creating leading directories must be a part of file creation function? At least it would be non-atomic. What if such function already created directory but can't create file (e.g. no space left)? Remove leading directories back or leave as is?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Standard C doesn't even *have* the concept of directories or folders - because there are systems where those don't exist.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That’s right, but those systems that do (e.g. POSIX, which has `mkdir`, and which is where `ENOENT` is coming from) implement them as described. If your system only exposes (say) object storage (though that’s definitely *not* what they had in mind back then) then obviously things are different.

Comment: @basedchad21 :  that is a different question - post a new question.  The standard library does not support directory creation, because the filesystem is platform specific, including hierarchical file systems.  The path is passed verbatim to the underlying OS or filesystem, and typically an OS will not create an arbitrary path. It is no different from say at the command shell,  entering `echo "some text" > /somedir/sample.txt`. If `somedir` does not exist you get an error, you have to use `mkdir` before hand, and the POSIX library for example provides a corresponding function for that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people in the comments have alluded, the error can happen if there is a non-existent folder.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp, *fp1;
    fp = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("error");
        exit(1);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    
    fp1 = fopen("nonexistent_folder/file.txt", "w");
    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        perror("error");
        exit(1);
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    
    return 0;
}
```

RESULTS:
fp works fine
fp1 fails with `error: No such file or directory`